# What is the "referral|ut" medium in Google Analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working on a PHP application that utilizes the Google Analytics API. When using the dimension "[ga:medium](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/trafficsources#ga%3amedium)" I expected three possible values: "organic", "referral" or "(none)". My application recently crashed because I got an unexpected value: "referral|ut". I haven't read anything about the pipe symbol in the API docs. Can anybody shed some light on this?